# SELECT statement filtering by time of day

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table A, columns OrderId, OrderTimeStamp (datetime).

I want to SELECT all records for any date, but between 10 am and 1 pm, for example.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
declare @t table(d datetime)

insert @t values('2012-01-01 09:00'),('2012-01-01 10:00'),('2012-01-01 11:00')

select cast(d as time) from @t where  cast(d as time) between '10:00' and '13:00'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot t-clausen for you continuous involvement in this one. I chose ntziolis' because I don't like (translate that as 'I dont understand') those declares, inserts and the '@'.

Comment: @Amarundo it is just a temporary table to illustrate that it works. The actual code is:  cast(OrderTimeStamp as time) between '10:00' and '13:00'

Comment: @Amarundo t-clausen is correct, this is just a short script to be able to test it without any existing tables but the actual statement (last line) is doing the same thing as mine, in fact it might even perform better because of the `BETWEEN`

Comment: @Amarundo I posted the correct code hours before anyone else. My code was very different from all the other solutions. So it could be hard for you to determine which code to pick. So i pointed out why the other solutions were not valid. You picking an answer that was posted hours after i posted mine is a bad choice.

Answer (score 4):

In T-SQL `DatePart` will do the trick:

To get all records from `10:00` - `12:59`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA
  WHERE DATEPART(hh, [OrderTimeStamp]) >= 10 AND DATEPART(hh, [OrderTimeStamp]) < 13
```

Or if you want to get all records from `10:00` - `13:00` (seconds/milliseconds are omitted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA
  WHERE DATEPART(hh, [OrderTimeStamp]) >= 10 AND DATEPART(hh, [OrderTimeStamp]) < 13
  OR (DATEPART(hh, [OrderTimeStamp]) = 13 AND DATEPART(mi, [OrderTimeStamp]) = 0)
```

Keep in mind that 24h values are returned from the `DatePart` function when used with `hh` as a format.

For further info see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

**UPDATE**

Since ouy are working with SQL 2008, you can make use of the `TIME`data type and make your query much simpler (and correct as well):

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA
  WHERE CONVERT(TIME(7), [OrderTimeStamp ]) >= '10:00:00.0000000' 
  AND CONVERT(TIME(7), [OrderTimeStamp ]) <= '13:00:00.0000000'
```

For futher info see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx

Comment: This will include times like 13:59

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You are 100% correct, it's one of these things you overlook each time, I have updated my answer with 2 options on how to handle this

Comment: sorry to say this, but it will still fail for seconds and milliseconds (13:00:59 997)

Comment: xD once again, 100% correct. Just came up with another option using the Time `DateType` in SQL 2008, looks way simpler than specifying more `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I like this one the most because it's just a statement without declares, inserts, etc. And also because you didn't give up! :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from TableA
where datepart(hh, OrderTimeStamp) >= 10 and datepart(hh, OrderTimeStamp) < 13
```

update:

doh, ntziolis beat me by 30 seconds.  one thing to note, if you want 1pm included, be sure to make the last part of the where <=.  if you want to only go up to 12:59.999 pm < is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from tableA
where datepart(hh, OrderTimeStamp) between 10 and 13
```

if you need to filter by minutes (like 13:20 and 14:15), try the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710255/how-can-i-write-a-where-clause-in-sql-to-filter-a-datetime-column-by-the-time-of) link

Comment: This will fail and include all timestamps between 13 and 14

Comment: humm, I don't think so. I just tested. Can you be more specific?

Comment: try this: select *  from (select cast('2012-01-01 13:30' as datetime) d) a where datepart(hh, d) between 10 and 13

Comment: but mate, he want the dates between 10 am and 1 pm. 13:30 is AFTER 1 pm, of course it wont include this record

Comment: Please try my query, it shows that 13:30 is included (it is your query)